# Why doesn't libicudata.so get smaller when I remove items from the data library?

Tags: linux, icu

I'm trying to build a custom ICU with a minimal data set.  I've tried to follow the instructions at [Reducing the Size of ICU's Data: Conversion Tables](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata#TOC-Customizing-ICU-s-Data-Library), but many of the files referenced don't exist in the ICU 4.8.1 source distribution.  Specifically, I cannot find any files that match ucm*.mk.

I've also tried creating reslocal.mk files as indicated in e.g. ICU's source/data/lang/resfiles.mk.  That did not help either.  My build is the typical:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/some/dir
$ make
$ make install
```

Regardless of what I do, libicudata.so.48.1 is about 17M.  It shouldn't matter, but I'm building on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the note at the top of that page: (see

> Note that ICU for C by default comes with pre-built data. The source
>   data files are not included unless ICU is downloaded from the
>   [source repository](http://site.icu-project.org/repository%20repository). Alternatively, the [Data Customizer](http://apps.icu-project.org/datacustom/%20Data%20Customizer) may be used to
>   customize the pre-built data.

Your ICU is reading the prebuilt package from `icu/source/data/in/*.dat` and ignoring the .mk files. We have had requests for the source data to be included as a downloadable .zip and so we plan to do this in the future.

If you have any suggestions for how our instructions can be made more clear, please file a bug. I've added a copy of that notice to the section you referenced.